# How to parse an empty XML element if it has attributes?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xstream

I'm using the XStream library to parse XML into objects. My problem is that the XML schema (admittedly it's not very good, but it's also out of my control) specifies that a certain element has all of its data in its attributes like so:

```
<Player machineIdentifier="41412kj423nkj234" platform="Chrome" product="Plex Web" state="playing" title="Plex Web (Chrome)" />
```

My class for the `Player` element:

```
@XStreamAlias("Player")
public class Player {

    @XStreamAlias("platform")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String platform;

    @XStreamAlias("product")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String product;

    @XStreamAlias("title")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String name;

    // Getters-setters ommited for brevity
}
```

Since the element is technically empty, `XStream.fromXML()` produces an object where the `Player` field is null.

How can I get XStream to still parse and instantiate the `Player` object so that I could use the attributes?

**Edit for Aniket's answer**

I'm using the `processAnnotations()` method. Since the actual schema is more than just a `Player` element, it wouldn't even work without processing the annotations.

My "objectifier" class (I've made more generic since there are multiple schemas I'm working with):

```
public class XMLObjectifier {

    // Other models omitted for brevity
    private Class[] sessionModel = new Class[]{
            PlexSessionResponse.class,
            Player.class,
            User.class,
            Video.class
    };

    public Object toObject(String xml, ModelType type) {
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.ignoreUnknownElements();
        switch (type) {
            case STATUS:
                xStream.processAnnotations(statusModel);
                break;
            case SESSION:
                xStream.processAnnotations(sessionModel);
                break;
        }
        return xStream.fromXML(xml);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem.

First I did

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\athakur\\Desktop\\data.txt");
    XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    Player player =  (Player) xStream.fromXML(file);
    System.out.println(player.getName() + " : " + player.getPlatform() + " : " +  player.getProduct());
}
```

and the output I got was -

> null : null : null

which is exactly what you are facing I guess. What you need to do is provide xstream instance with the information of Player class before hand so that it does un-marshaling correctly. Following code worked for me -

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\athakur\\Desktop\\data.txt");
    XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    xStream.processAnnotations(Player.class); // This is required
    Player player =  (Player) xStream.fromXML(file);
    System.out.println(player.getName() + " : " + player.getPlatform() + " : " +  player.getProduct());
}
```

And the output is -

> Plex Web (Chrome) : Chrome : Plex Web

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do use the `processAnnotations()` method. Please see updated question.